# Is there a difference between fn : ('a -> 'b) * ('a -> 'b) * 'a list -> 'b list and fn : ('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list

Tags: sml, smlnj

I wrote a function

```
fun map_alternate (f,g,lst) =
    case lst of
        []   => []
      | a::b => f a ::  map_alternate (g, f, lst)
```

and its type is:

```
 ('a -> 'b) * ('a -> 'b) * 'a list -> 'b list
```

But when I changed parenthesis like this

```
fun map_alternate f g lst =
    case lst of
         []   => []
       | a::b => (f a) :: (map_alternate g f rest)
```

it produces different type:

```
fn : ('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list
```

So what is different?

Comment: See [What is 'Currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36321/1088827).

Answer (score 1):

You removed one pair of parentheses and added another two.

The parentheses in `(f a) :: (map_alternate g f rest)` make no difference. They can be omitted.

The parentheses in

```
fun map_alternate (f, g, lst) =
    case lst of
        []   => []
      | a::b => f a ::  map_alternate (g, f, lst)
```

actually carries the a meaning: This function takes *one* argument, a 3-tuple, pattern matches each three components and eventually calls itself with a modification of that 3-tuple (with the 1st and 2nd elements interchanged).

In contrast, the function

```
fun map_alternate f g lst =
    case lst of
         []   => []
       | a::b => f a :: map_alternate g f rest
```

carries a different meaning. It is equivalent to

```
val rec map_alternate = fn f => fn g => fn lst =>
    case lst of
         []   => []
       | a::b => f a :: map_alternate g f rest
```

and is a function that takes an argument `f` and returns a function that takes an argument `g` and returns a function that takes an argument `lst` and returns `case lst of ...`. That is, a [*curried*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying/36321#36321) version of a three-argument function rather than a *tupled*. Functions returning functions involve more `->`s in the type signature.